# What is the best way to migrate or export/import data from Microsoft AX4 to AX7

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

On the one side I have a working AX4 environment and now want to upgrade to the new AX7.

Therefore we need some tables of the database to be imported or migrated to the new one.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Your question about data migration is currently not programming related. Because of that you may want to ask somewhere else, e.g. the [Dynamics AX community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33).

Comment: Thank you. I will also try it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct upgrade path from AX4 to AX7 (AFAIK), nor is there a way to directly move objects.

How many objects need migrated?  You're essentially left with two options.

1. XPO objects into AX 2012 staging environment, then upload the AX 2012 modelstore to LCS and that will migrate the code and create the migration project in AX7 (See https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/upg101-preparing-for-migration/)
2. Recreate the objects by hand :(

A little more detail on (1.) is in AX 2012, instead of the code being stored on disk in a bunch of layer files, it's stored in a separate SQL database. And a modelstore is conceptually a *.bak file of that database. So when you import an XPO into AX 4.0 `CUS` layer, it ends up in axCUS.aod; likewise when you import an XPO in AX 2012, it ends up in the `modelstore` in the `CUS` layer.

To uplift code in `AX7` from `AX12`, you basically take that `*.modelstore` file and `.zip (compress)` it and upload it on `lcs.dynamics.com`. You also must connect `LCS` to `VSO (visual studio online)`, because it creates tasks and things to do.

You then wait a while (usually about an hour, but I've had it take 1-2 days when they were changing the framework), then you have the objects in `VSO` and you can sync them to your `AX7` environment.

**EDIT:** Regarding data from AX 4.0...I'm definitely not yet an expert on getting data into `AX7` but they generally push data entities, which are essentially an abstraction of parts of the database.  If it's one-time data moves, you can possibly use the `Excel data connector`.

See these resource:

- http://msdax7.blogspot.com/2016/02/open-to-excel-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax.html
- http://msdax7.blogspot.com/2016/02/exportimport-data-using-data-management.html
- https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/data-entities/

Comment: I think Virtrel is not asking about the table definition, but about the data in the tables.

Comment: Oh I think you're right. He only mentioned `data` in the question title and I glossed over it.

Comment: Yes it is about the data in the tables. Sorry for vague defnied title.